# What is the Interface in This URL in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

In `Get` Method:

`http://xyz.erprnd.com/api/v1/customers/get?yearmonth=201807`

My design interface:

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@GET("customers/{get}/{yearmonthValue}")
Call<CustResponse> CustomerData(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
                                @Path("get") String get,
                                @Query("yearmonth") String yearmonth,
                                @Path("yearmonthValue") String yearmonthValue,
                                @Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

What can I change to make this work properly?

Comment: any error or compilation output to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Please refer to [ask] and [mcve], and update your question so that it is clear what you are trying to do and what you have already tried.

Comment: i am really sorry for that i shouldn't post this post in this way since i got error on my project ... As soon as possible i will update it or remove it . Thnx Andrew Fan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, double check that you are passing "http://xyz.erprnd.com/api/v1" as your **baseUrl** when building Retrofit.

Then, base on the URL you posted, the interface should look something like:

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
@GET("customers/get")
Call<CustResponse> CustomerData(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
                                @Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
                                @Query("yearmonth") String yearmonth);
```

when you define query parameters, you just need to add the annotation @Query("param_name") and then the value of the variable passed in will be transform intro:    `param_name=variable_value`

Also, I removed your @Path("get") parameter, since it seems that that part of the URL will always be `/get` and won't change.
Unfortunately, I cannot test it since I don't have authorization to your API.

Comment: And i really sorry i can not provide the actual Auth key Since My Client not permit for Security Issue .. but your Solution is Perfect Thanks Again.

Comment: Glad I could help!